# C# Generics - is it possible to put constraints on a method to only accept DataTable and String?

Tags: c#-4.0, generics

I want to do this:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T myArg) where T: DataTable, String
{
    ...
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Well, for the compiler that would make little sense - how would it know which one is passed in? Can you explain what your use case for such a method would be?

Comment: Query or DataTable; if query, I create my own datatable, if datatable, I work with the data.  It almost looks like I should just have two methods, but that's ugly and I can't have overloads with the same number of params, but different types.  So it'd be something like MyMethodUsingString() or MyMethodUsingDataTable().  Gross.

Comment: It may be ugly (to your sensibilities), but it is the correct solution. You are not really using generics here (or rather, you are abusing them).

Comment: Why can't they be different methods with different types?

Comment: @Oded, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be infinitely preferable to make it two separate methods.

```
public void MyMethod(DataTable myArg)
{
    ...
}

public void MyMethod(String myArg)
{
    ...
}
```

or, if generic (I'm not sure why generic is needed in this case)

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T myArg) where T: DataTable
{
    ...
}

public void MyMethodStr<T>(T myArg) where T: string
{
    ...
}
```

or worse case, throw errors if not one of those types. That is least preferable as it will throw at runtime not compile.

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T myArg)
{
    if(myArg is String == false && myString is DataTable == false)
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(...);
}
```

But besides that, no.

Comment: If I'm going to have separate methods, I don't need to make them generic.  Also, you can't have string as a constraint, from what I gather.

Comment: Oh, and you can't have overloads with the same number of params, either, so your first idea won't work.. but, I can do MyMethodString(string arg) and MyMethodDataTable(DataTable arg).

Comment: You can have overloads with the same number of parameters. They just cannot be of the same type.